# Javascript performe action after animation end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the text after the animation is done but I have a hard time to find something that works. I have tried timers but that dont realy work beacuse the animation time is different every time (will add that later but now it is same every time).

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1

            var moveTime;
            if (r == '1') {
                moveTime = 5000;
            } else if (r == '2') {
                moveTime = 4900;
            }
            var slowDown = 1000;
            var $div = $('div').css('left', 0);

            while (moveTime > 0) {
                slowDown--;
                $div.animate({
                    left: moveTime + "px"
                }, 3000);

                if (slowDown > 0) {
                    slowDown--;
                    moveTime = 0;
                }

                slowDown--;
                moveTime--;
            }

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = r;


        });

    });
```

```css
    div {
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        margin: 200px 0 0 -8400px;
        width: 10000px;
        height: 125px;
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 125px, #000000 125px, #000000 250px)
    }
    
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 130px 0 0 0;
        font-size: 90px;
    }
    
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button>Start Animation</button>
    <div></div>
    <h1 id="timer">|</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Step 1: [Read the `animate` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method to map your animations to an array of promises, then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to do something when all have resolved:

```
var promisesArr = [];

while (moveTime > 0) {
    // ...

    promisesArr.push($div.animate({
       left: moveTime + "px"
    }, 3000).promise());

    // ...
}

Promise.all(promisesArr).then(function() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = r;
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/817t7kbz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

see official api for [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

you should be able to just call $(elem).animate().animate() and the second animate will only start when the first ends...

additionally, animate function takes a 'easing' parameter, something like "easein" will probably do what you want without needing to keep track of time at all.